# Possession in Basketball

Tags: basketball, statistics

I am having trouble understanding possessions in basketball as it seems like there are 3 equations. One that is (FGA+0.44*FTA+TO) and another that accounts for Offensive Rebounds found [here](https://www.sportsrec.com/calculate-teams-offensive-defensive-efficiencies-7775395.html). Lastly, the main one created by Dean Oliver found [here](https://www.basketball-reference.com/about/ratings.html). Are the first two estimates of possession, as in a much simply way to calculate possession?

My question stems from looking at some formulas like TOV% and Points per Possession. Seems like TOV uses the equation found above and PpP uses Oliver's equation. Why does this difference exist? Also are players TOV%/PpP different than a team's TOV%/PpP? I feel like the calculation should be the same, but using the teams numbers instead of a players.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is Possession acording to **[SportingCharts](https://www.sportingcharts.com/dictionary/nba/possession.aspx)**:

> A statistic in basketball defined as the time a team gains offensive possession of the ball until it scores, loses the ball, or commits a violation or foul. A possession in basketball is an important statistic because it allows teams to compute statistics on a per possession basis. The statistic can be applied to an individual player or the entire team.

Now we know what possession is, we can go further: **how to calculate possession in Basketball?**

The more realistic possession estimator is **poss = FGA + 0.475 x FTA - ORB + TO**

**FGA** - the number of field goal attempts

**FTA** - the number of free throw attempts

**ORB** - the number of offensive rebounds

**TO** - the number of turnovers.  Possessions end on turnovers and on shots that the offense doesn't rebound.

**0.475 -** The [**consensus value**](http://kenpom.com/blog/index.php/weblog/help_with_team_page/) for college basketball seems to be 0.475.  In the NBA, 0.44 is typically used.

A [**good pdf**](http://bookwormsports.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/CB_SPG-EBook1-FINAL-07-28-15.pdf) about this formula.

Comment: Thank you. So you are saying probably ignore Oliver's method and use the above? For both Team and Player Points per Possesison. Then for TOV% use the predefined one.

Comment: I think yes. The formula **FGA + 0.475 x FTA - ORB + TO** to calculate the possession (team or individual) and you can use the **TOV%** to calculate especially the percentage of turnover by a player.